# Python, installed script fails mistaking a namespace for a module

Tags: python, setuptools

We have a number of Python scripts which are implemented (as is
right and proper) in modules.  The `setup.py` for these includes

```
setup(
  :
  packages = ['sv.sd5ls'],
  namespace_packages = ['sv'],
  scripts = ['bin/sd5-ls'],
  :
```

which explicitly declares the namespace and module(s) for the package.
In particular, we don't use the `find_packages()` facility provided by
setuptools (we only have one or two modules, so we don't really need
it).

This all works fine on the development machine (which uses Python 3.6.9
and the stock OS setuptools 39.0.1, also on CI which has Python 3.6.10
and setuptools 40.8.0, again stock OS.

One colleague has issues on running the installed package (in fact all
of them)

```
$ sd5-ls --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sd5-ls", line 4, in <module>
  __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('svsd5-sd5ls==6.0a2', 'sd5-ls')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
    line 667, in run_script
  self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
    line 1471, in run_script
  exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/svsd5_sd5ls-6.0a2-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/sd5-ls",
    line 3, in <module>
__requires__ = 'svsd5-sd5ls==6.0a2'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sv'
```

Inspecting the `dist-packages` directory

```
drwxr-sr-x  5 root staff   4096 May 18 11:27 pkg_resources
drwxr-sr-x  6 root staff   4096 May 18 11:27 setuptools
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   4096 May 18 11:27 setuptools-46.4.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff   5602 Jun 23 11:27 svsd5_sd5ls-6.0a2-py3.6.egg
```

Note the *much* more-recent version of setuptools, and the `pkg_resources` directory
created at the same time as that was installed.  The only mention of `pkg_resources`
in our code is `sd5-ls/sv/__init__.py` which contains the line

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

as suggested in the Python namespace documentation. Note that the backtrace above
includes a call to `pkg_resources/__init__.py`.  My guess is that this is the problem.
The installed program shim (autogenerated) is just

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'svsd5-sd5ls==6.0a2','sd5-ls'
__requires__ = 'svsd5-sd5ls==6.0a2'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('svsd5-sd5ls==6.0a2', 'sd5-ls')
```

and I think that the target `pkg_resources` is the virtual one embedded in the `.egg`
file, but in error we pick up the pre-existing one in the `dist-packages` directory
and that is incompatible.

Does this sound right?  In which case, removing the pre-existing `pkg_resources` would/should fix the issue, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

In fact I find a solution in a comment in [this repository](https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages)

> Zipped eggs don't play nicely with namespace packaging, and may be implicitly installed by commands like python setup.py install. To prevent this, it is recommended that you set `zip_safe=False` in `setup.py`, as we do here.